# Is it possible to programmatically create a drawable and assign it to an ImageView?

Tags: android

So I'm trying to somehow create a Path object in code (no XML) and draw it into an ImageView.  Problem is I can't figure out any way to programmatically create ANY shape and have it show up in my ImageView.  I can easily assign the ImageView to an XML resource and that works fine like this:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.resourcename);
```

Here's the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <size
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#00f"
        />
</shape>
```

But if I do something like this code below which I thought should work, it compiles and runs without errors, but nothing happens.  I tried to create a simple RectShape and assign the ImageView to it with setImageDrawable.  Am I totally barking up the wrong tree here?  I am extremely new to Android coding fyi, so I very well may be way off here.  I do notice that I'm never manually drawing the rectangle, do I have to do that somewhere?  I sort of figured the ImageView would take care of it, but maybe not.  Let me know if you need more information about my code.

```
RectShape rect = new RectShape();
rect.resize(50,50);
ShapeDrawable sdRect = new ShapeDrawable(rect);
sdRect.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
sdRect.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
imageView.setImageDrawable(sdRect);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I took a glance at the [Drawable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java#Drawable.createFromXmlInner%28android.content.res.Resources%2Corg.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser%2Candroid.util.AttributeSet%29) source and it looks like the XML tag `<shape>` inflates to `GradientDrawable` not `ShapeDrawable`. Replace your code with this:

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
gd.setColor(Color.BLACK);
imageView.setImageDrawable(gd);
```

Comment: Ah yes, that does it!  Unfortunately that means my true purpose may not be possible, which was to set a Path object to a PathShape, to a ShapeDrawable, to the source of the ImageView.  I'm not sure if there's a way to get a Path object into a GradientDrawable.  But at least now I know how to make some shapes show up, thanks!

Comment: In that case try combining [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495953/how-are-you-supposed-to-use-a-shapedrawable-with-a-pathshape-to-draw-a-line-on-a) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133051/shapedrawablefrom-a-pathshape-not-drawing-on-correct-coordinates).

Comment: Gotcha, will try.  I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You must set width and height ShapeDrawable. In your code sample size is 0, so you don't see rect

```
sdRect.setIntrinsicWidth(50)
sdRect.setIntrinsicHeight(50)
```